# Excluding Data Values which common column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently, I've got a single set of data in which I want to exclude based on if a condition is meet. The group has a common column reference.

```
Name      Sequence      Value    
-----------------------------------
Text         1              1       
Don          1             30       
Text         2              0      
Sid          2            240      
Florence     2            300
Text         3            200
Casper       3             20
Cat          3             10
Text         4              0
Dem          4             50
```

Basically any row in which `Text` is not equal to 0 needs to be excluded be excluded. In addition the rows in which share the same sequence. Expected outcome is to only have data from sequence 2 and 4.

Comment: Data pulled needs to only have Text, when equal to 0 which corresponding data with the same position.

Comment: you wants to exclude Name= 'Text' where Value= 1?

Comment: @mkrabbani. Yes, excluding name text where value 1 and values with the same position.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with NOT EXISTS as below-

```
SELECT Name,
Position,
Value
FROM your_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Name,Position,Value
    FROM your_table
    WHERE (Name = 'Text' AND Value = 1)
    OR (Position = Value)
)
```

As you are looking for options other than NOT EXISTS, you can try this below-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE [Sequence] NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Sequence] 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE [Name] = 'Text' 
    AND [Value] <> 0 
)
```

Comment: @ mkRabbani : Is there a way to nest this and use <> instea of Not exists. In this example TEST can be 1 or 200, or any number. I don't want anything that doesn't equal to 0.

Comment: Then this is easier if you select equal to 0. Right? You can explain full scenario for better understanding.

Comment: My data set will have several sequences. In each sequence there a set a values pulled. So, those values will share the same sequence. There would be up to 20 plus sequences. Within each set is a row, like my example "Test" which will have either a 1 or zero. When this row for the sequence has zero, its a good data set. when the row is not equal to zero, then its a bad dataset. So, i'm wanting to exclude any group that has the bad dataset based on this condition.

Comment: My current query, pulls all of the data, but mixed in there is this row that has a non zero value for this row and the subsequent data within that sequence is no good. I want to ignore it.

Comment: For either 1 or zero. It could be 2000 or 1, or 100. any number. when its not zero, those are values I'm not interested in.

Comment: You wants only Row= 3 from your sample data? If I am wrong, better if you can edit your sample data for all scenario and then add your expected output from them.

Comment: Just edited my post with more data. and expected outcome

Comment: @Diego83 can you check the updated script and fiddle here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25bd12062ef3293e09a7262b4aaec23e

Comment: @ mkRabbani : My output was blank. I have it nested within a where clause of the original query.  PVXMEDE.SEQUENCE NOT IN (Select Distinct PVXMEDE.SEQUENCE FROM PVXMEDE WHERE PVXMEDE.PAT_ID = 'INVALID' AND PVXMEDE.NUM_VALUE <> 0)

Comment: Please first check separately what your SubQuery returns. Then check the out put is expected or not. Syntax wise your code seems fine to me.

Comment: @Diego83 Any success?

Comment: @Diego83 . . . `NOT EXISTS` is the best solution to this question.  mkRabbani should not have removed that answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added my initial query as well to the answer.

Comment: @mkRabbani  I've ended up filtering in SSRS. For the query piece, I wasn't getting any results successfully.